# Fotorama thumbnails creation dynamically using php

Tags: php, mysql, fotorama

```
<div class="fotorama" data-width="700" data-ratio="700/467" data-max-width="100%" align="center" data-arrows="true" data-click="false" data-swipe="false" data-autoplay="2000" data-nav="thumbs">

<?php
    $query="select * from released_movies" ;
    $queryr=$con->query($query);
    while($row=$queryr->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

    <div>
        <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $row['rel_id'];?>">
            <img u="image" src="../AbaamAdmin/Released_Movies/<?php echo $row['rel_movies_pics'];?>" />
        </a>
    </div>

<?php }?>
</div>
```

I need to create a fotorama gallery slideshow with thumbnails of the larger image. But by giving the above code, no image appears as thumbnail instead I got only a thumbnail border. How I will get the thumbnail image there dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your image path

Comment: what is `u=image` in `<img u="image"`?

Comment: Actually u="image" was previously done for some css property. Even if I remove that , I am not getting the thumbnail images. But the bigger images are working.

Comment: there might be image path problem as i told before

Comment: remove `<div></div>` inside the loop, will fix the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ab4f2zL1/

Comment: But removing div is not working.